# How to convert the txt file to tmx file using python

Tags: python-3.x, txt, tmx

I scraped some contents from the websites and stored them using the txt format. I want to convert the txt file to the tmx file but only find the reverse way. Is there any method that I can convert a txt file to a tmx file?

Comment: By change, do you mean changing the extension while leaving the contents of the file the same?

Comment: Yes, since the txt is the plain content, I want to generate the tmx(translation memory eXchange) format so that I can use it in Computer-assisted Translation tools.